# How do I find the ptep for a given address?

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel

I'm trying to write a function that write-protects every `pte` in a given `vm_area_struct`. What is the function that gives me the `ptep` for a given address? I have:

```
pte_t *ptep;
for (addr = start; addr < end; addr += PAGE_SIZE) {
    ptep = WHATS_THIS_FUNCTION_CALLED(addr);
    ptep_set_wrprotect(mm, addr, ptep);
}
```

What's the `WHATS_THIS_FUNCTION_CALLED` called?

Comment: What about `follow_page()` with `FOLL_GET` flag?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is to use `__get_locked_pte` . However, I would advise against it since there are much better (efficient and fair in terms of resource contention) ways to accomplish your goal.

In linux, the typical idiom for traversing page tables is with a nested for loop four levels deep (four is the number of page table levels linux supports). For examples, see `copy_page_range` and `apply_to_page_range` [in mm/memory.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/memory.c?v=2.6.38#L847). In fact, if you look closely at `copy_page_range`, it is called when forking from `dup_mmap` in kernel/fork.c. It operates on an entire `vm_area_struct` essentially.

You can replicate the idiom used in either of those functions. There are some caveats, however. For example, `copy_page_range` fully supports transparent hugepages (2.6.38) by using a completely separate `copy_huge_pmd` inside `copy_pmd_range`. Unless you want to write two separate functions (one for normal pages and one for transparent huge pages, see `Gracefull fallback` in `Documentation/vm/transhuge.txt`.

The point is that virtual memory in linux is very complicated, so be sure to completely understand every possible use case. `follow_page` in [mm/memory.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/memory.c?v=2.6.38#L1268) should demonstrate how to cover all of your bases.

Comment: Also `pagewalk` mechanism can be used as the start point. Look at [mm/pagewalk.c](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.2.9/mm/pagewalk.c#L189).

Comment: `pagewalk` mechanism was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for either the function `virt_to_pte` as defined [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/tile/mm/pgtable.c#L392) or your own re-implementation of it.

This function uses `pte_offset_kernel(pmd_t * dir, unsigned long address)` which takes a pmd (Page mid-level Directory) structure and an address , though one could also use `pte_offset(pmd_t * dir, unsigned long address)`.

See [Linux Device Drivers 3rd Edition Chapter 15](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-15.shtml) or [Linux Device Drivers, 2nd Edition Chapter 13 mmap and DMA](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch13.html) for further references.